# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found while running python file from ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi  ,

I am trying to run a python application from aws ec2 instacne , but i am getting the below error .

```
sh-4.2$ python3 Landing.py
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Can some one let me know how can we solve the issue.

Thanks,
Nikhil